# Global variable referencing variables in a for loop is not set correctly

Tags: bash, shell-script

Here is my example snippet

```
text="Var 1 is ${one}, Var 2 is ${two}, Var 3 is ${three}"
for (( i=0 ; i<1 ; i++ ))
do
 one="one"
 two="two"
 three="three"
 echo "${text}"
done
```

returns

```
Var 1 is , Var 2 is , Var 3 is
```

and if I change the code to this, it works as expected:

```
text="Var 1 is ${one}, Var 2 is ${two}, Var 3 is ${three}"
for (( i=0 ; i<1 ; i++ ))
do
 one="one"
 two="two"
 three="three"
 echo "Var 1 is ${one}, Var 2 is ${two}, Var 3 is ${three}"
done
```

Comment: explain us what is unexpected on the first example?

Comment: maybe I should rephrase it--how can I make the output match example 2, without having the full text echoed each in each for loop.  My goal is re-usability across multiple conditionals and loops.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because at the moment you set the 'text' variable, all the others are empty, defaulting to empty string "".

Try setting `text` as you command and save it with (') and not with (") so bash doesn't evaluate you expression, then if you do.

```
$ text='echo "var1 = $one var2 = $two"' 
$ one=hi
$ two=bye
```

then `eval $text` will return `var1 = hi var2 = bye`